# How can I apologize and promise that a mistake won't happen again?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request

I want to apologize for some mistake in official mail and want to make them sure I will not do that again.

> "I will take care of this next time" .

or

> "I will take care of this onwards".

Comment: take care of something means to handle something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could simply say:

> "I apologize for the error and it will not happen again."

Answer (score 2):

Steve's suggestion is the best, but if you want to apologise in a more formal way, then: *I deeply regret what occurred, and I promise that I will make every effort and do everything in my power to prevent its reoccurrence*. (Very formal)

Answer (score 1):

1. *I'm really sorry for XYZ (i.e. for what happened). It won't ever happen again*.

Suitable for many situations where you realize you have made an awful blunder.

2. *Please forgive me. I committed a terrible error of judgement*.

This could be said to a family member or a friend when you need to express contrition. You can forgo the second sentence.

3. *Please accept my/our (most sincere) apology/apologies*. Needless to say, it will not happen again.

Terse and very formal, perhaps more appropriate in a business environment.